# How return all rows for groupBy

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I use the query to get the models that the user has, but only 1 model is returned for each user. How to get all? If I set `$count=3`  I should receive 3 or more models in group, but only first row is returned

```
$items->where(/*.....*/)
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->havingRaw("COUNT(*) >= {$count}")->get()
```

**UPDATE**
I solved it. I created a separate function for preparing the query and used it 2 times. 
I think this may be an incorrect solution, but it works

```
$items = Items::query();
$this->prepareQuery($request, $items)

$items->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($count, $request){

                $q->whereHas('items', function ($query) use ($request){
                    $this->prepareQuery($request, $query);
                }, '>=', $count);
            })
 ->paginate(4);
```

Comment: That's what `groupBy` does. If you have 10 items with the same `user_id` it will only return one.

Comment: How can this problem be solved?

Comment: use `->get();` instead groupBy

Answer (score 0):

If you have relationships set up you can quite simply call:

`$model->models()`

`$model` being the model you're wanting the list for.
`models()` being the name of the relationship between the two items.

For example, a post may have many comments. You can call `$post->comments()` to get a list of the posts comments.

You may also query this from the database directly with some eloquent magic.

`Post::with('comments')->where(/*....*/)->get();`

EDIT:

You can check to see if a model has X number of related models like so.

`Post::has('comments', '>=', 3)->where(/*...*/)->get();`

Comment: It does not fit in my case. I need to get all the models for users, if they are available in a certain amount from them.

Comment: I found a solution and wrote. Perhaps you look at it and understand what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This may work.Sometimes take can help.

```
$items->where(/*.....*/)
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->take({{$count}});
```